# RxJava: Get observable in onComplete

Tags: java, rx-java

I may be something very obvious here, but in the `onComplete()` method of an Observer, how do I get at which Observable has called onComplete?

More detail, say you have the following:

```
event.subscribe((e) -> {
},
(error) -> {
},
() -> {
// HERE - How do I tell what event source is completing?
}
```

Comment: Post some code sample because I don't understand the question. onComplete gets called on the same chain you created the Observable

Comment: @breakline added some detail

Comment: If I understand correctly: you cant. However I dont understand why you'd want it either. You can store the subscription itself and reference to it in onCompleted. Whatever you wanna do you should include it in the chain itself as after onCompleted your Observable basically does not exist anymore.

Comment: Also you can store an observable in a variable obviously, so you can reference back to it

Answer (score 0):

'event' is an observable. Every item emitted by the observable will go through the chain of operators. After an item went through the operators it will be redirected to the subscriber, which is happening in 'subscribe'. Subscribe provides two overloades. One for each emission of the stream (event) and the second one for noticing that the 'event'-Observable (stream) has been finished.

Lets look at a List, which will be converted in an Observable. If you convert an Array to an Observable with:

```
Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3);
```

you will get called for each value 1, 2, 3 onNext in the subscription. The observable will be "onComplete" after 3 has been pushed to onNext. Just look at the implementation on gitHub, to see what is happening.

Back to your question: How do I tell what event source is completing?
It would be the Observable 'event', because you are subscribing to it.

Comment: But how do you get a reference to the `event` object inside the `onComplete()` method (where the `event` object is not available in the enclosing lambda scope)?

Comment: What would you like to do with the reference? Maybe there is another way to do it.